# Create SharePoint WSP without DLL?

Tags: sharepoint, dll, visual-studio-2013, manifest, wsp

I'm trying to build a WSP using the Visual Studio 2013 template for SharePoint - without it including the primary DLL of the project.
I tried removing AssemblyInfo.cs and all the references, it still builds the DLL and includes it in the manifest.

Is there a way to configure the project so that it omits the primary DLL (even if it does build it)?

(If anyone asks the "why would you want to do that" question, i'd be happy to answer it but doing so won't help me.)

Thanks

-John

Comment: Never mind, found it. There is a project property "Include Assembly In Package".

Answer (score 1):

In project properties, set "Include Assembly in Package" to False. Then publish to generate your WSP file. This new WSP will not contain the DLL.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my comment of the original post. But thanks for doubling down on that! Now if I could just figure out how to keep Visual Studio from generating the DLL in the first place, that would be icing on the cake!